# Run third Activity from first Activity, and the third Activity must run second or back to first

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I have three Activities. first and second Activities has a button "doProcess". Third Activity execute some process. I want to do next scenaries (in pseudocode):

Scenary 1:

```
1) in FirstActivity click button "doProcess";
2) run ThirdActivity, put FirstActivity in backstack;
3)
if operation finish successful
    destroy FirstActivity;
    run SecondActivity and put here result;
    destroy ThirdActivity;
else
    back to FirstActivity;
    destroy ThirdActivity;
```

Scenary 2:

```
1) in SecondActivity click button "doProcess";
2) run ThirdActivity, put SecondActivity in backstack;
3)
if operation finish successful
    back to SecondActivity and put here result;
    destroy ThirdActivity;
else
    back to SecondActivity;
    destroy ThirdActivity;
```

Could you explain me what methods i need to call from each Activity for running other activity which i need. I understand that for Scenary 2 I may run `startActivityForResult()` from SecondActivity and override `onActivityResult()`. And in ThirdActivity I call the `setResult()` method. But i'm not understand how to do the Scenary 1.

Answer (score 0):

The `onActivityResult(...)` invokes by system before `onResume()` that's why we can redirect intent from thirdActivity to secondActivity.

Here is the code. In `onCreateView()` we start second activity with `startActivityForResult()`. When the result is returned by secondActivity, will be running an `onActivityResult()`. In this method we take result from intent, called data, and then put it into a new intent. Then we start secondActivity with this intent by invoking `startActivity()`.

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        scanBarcodeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
        ...
    }

    // intent redirecting
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(data == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SecondActivity.class);
        ...
        intent.putExtra(...);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```